# Why can I see though my Mesh (even in renders)?

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I have a 3D model of a computer processor and I think I messed up some settings.

I can see through the head of the processor and the pins below the process unit are visible and I know that this problem is not because of **Camera View Clipping** because I can see the top part texture of the head.

*Note:* I' using EEVEE engine.

[image]

**No inverted normals:**

[image]

Comment: Quick guess: Your normals are inverted and you have enabled backface culling?

Comment: @haarigertroll no inverted normals , how to switch off backfuace culling

Comment: @haarigertroll Figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was blend mode , the blend mode was set to alpha blend , when i changed it to alpha hashed , it got solved